# Is it possible to set the schema in the JDBC connection string for sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect to sql server using by Java application. While connecting to H2 database, I appended `schema=schema_name` to the connection string in my java application and that worked.

However the same does not works for sqlserver.Connection is established but if my query does not contains the schema name prior to table name then query execution fails.

Please let me know of JDBC supports schema name in connection string or their is any other way.

Comment: Please show a connection string you are using.

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver://195.16.212.265:1433;databaseName = DFTK;schema=Demo_Schema

Comment: You need to change the default schema for that user in SQL Server. I don't think there is a different way

Comment: @Ravi: there is no `schema` parameter for the MS JDBC driver: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx

Comment: Thanks.
I will create my tables directly in dbo as that will simplify things.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, that is not possible. What you might want to do is set default schema for that user instead.

```
create login foo with password = "superstronkpassword";
create user foober for login foo with default_schema = "my super schema";
```